# How do I remove an unwanted word on python using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started learning Python, every white level knowledge. I am trying to webscrape from a website and tweet it.

Here's my code.

```
def scrape ():
    page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    home = soup.find(class_="editorial-franchise-layout__main__3cLBl")
    posts = home.find_all(class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__inherit-font__1Y8w3 text__inherit-size__1DZJi link__underline_on_hover__2zGL4")
    top_post = posts[0].find("h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").text.strip()
    
    tweet (top_post)
```

The result :

```
FTX ex-CEO Bankman-Fried claims he was unaware of improper use of customer funds -ABC News, article with image
```

I want to get rid of "article with image"

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the span element within h3 to get your desired output

**Change**

```
top_post = posts[0].find(
"h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").text.strip()
```

to

```
top_post = posts[0].find(
"h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").find_all("span")[0].text.strip()
```

**Full Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/business/future-of-money/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
home = soup.find(class_="editorial-franchise-layout__main__3cLBl")
posts = home.find_all(class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__inherit-font__1Y8w3 text__inherit-size__1DZJi link__underline_on_hover__2zGL4")
top_post = posts[0].find(
"h3", class_="text__text__1FZLe text__dark-grey__3Ml43 text__medium__1kbOh text__heading_3__1kDhc heading__base__2T28j heading__heading_3__3aL54 hero-card__title__33EFM").find_all("span")[0].text.strip()

print(top_post)
```

**Output**

```
FTX ex-CEO Bankman-Fried claims he was unaware of improper use of customer funds -ABC News
```